# docker nginx-proxy config per virtual host

Tags: docker, nginx, virtual-hosts

I use this to generate a nginx-proxy in my ubuntu docker environment:
https://github.com/evertramos/docker-compose-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion

Then I created many container with virtual hosts for my different domains.
One of these containers is a joomla container, which needs a larger client_max_body_size.

In the evertramos repo I found an explanation how to set client_max_body_size for all virtual hosts, but I want to change it only for the specific domain.

Where do I have to create that file, how is it named and which contents are inside?

USE_NGINX_CONF_FILES=true is already set in .env

Answer (score 1):

It was too easy:

File in NGINX_FILES_PATH/example.com with

```
client_max_body_size = 100m;
```

nothing more.